# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

I am trying to get the host address by passing host name. But while running my code, I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at socketprogram_client.SocketProgram_Client.main(SocketProgram_Client.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error?

Here is my code:

```
package socketprogram_client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SocketProgram_Client 
{
    public static void main ( String args[] ) throws IOException 
    {
        String host_name = args[0];

        try
        {
            InetAddress my_ipaddr = InetAddress.getByName(host_name);
            System.out.println("Resolved to IP address: " + my_ipaddr.getHostAddress());
        }
        catch ( UnknownHostException e )
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find IP address for: " + host_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the code formatting in the original was unclear. When I added the formatting, it's perfectly possible that the line numbers changed and the exception being thrown on line 16 no longer corresponds to line 16.

Comment: Check if any args ar being passed. Do a System.out.println(args.length)

Comment: Or learn to debug your program.

Comment: And where is line 16 (which is clearly the line where the error occurs)?  What array is being indexed on that line?  How big is the array?  What is the index value?  Do you see a problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not passing any arguments.  You should do some checks:

```
public static void main ( String args[] ) throws IOException 
{
    if(args == null || args.length == 0){
        System.out.println("You didn't pass in any arguments!");
    }
    else{
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

When running the program, you must have an argument in the command line:

```
java SocketProgram_Client the_argument
```

`the_argument` is the argument you're passing in (`args[0]`).

Comment: @Betlista Good catch!  I completely forgot `args` cannot be `null`.  Just a force of habit to check null before empty.

Comment: Actually, `args` can be null, if `main` is called from another method.  But one would not normally need to protect against that.

Comment: It's a good habbit, I thought about it more and it won't be null from command line, but programmer can call this method too...

Comment: @HotLicks Then there's no harm in having that check.

Answer (score -1):

You might not be passing an argument to `args` so `args[0]` could be null there.

```
package socketprogram_client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SocketProgram_Client 
{
    public static void main ( String args[] ) throws IOException 
    {
        if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("You didn't say a host name");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String host_name = args[0];

        try
        {
            InetAddress my_ipaddr = InetAddress.getByName(host_name);
            System.out.println("Resolved to IP address: " + my_ipaddr.getHostAddress());
        }
        catch ( UnknownHostException e )
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find IP address for: " + host_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked that ugh